# Subset does not work in R

Tags: r, subset

I just started to use R for some basic analysis. I was trying to use `subset`  to extract some data from one of my txt files. 
The head of my data file looks like this.

```
head(gps2)
         logFC        Pval    Gene
1 -0,155887003 0,872819236   Cidec
2 -2,853534804 0,158917555  Hsd3b5
3  1,031753975 0,120636931 Cyp2a22
4  0,323919709 0,292010361  Osbpl3
5 -2,842982917 0,039520301  Elovl3
6 -2,223250518  6,1759E-06 Sult5a1
```

And I was trying to get the subset with `Pval < 0.05` and `logFC < -0.5`.
I wrote the command as follows:

```
genelist=read.table('data.txt',header=T,stringsAsFactors = F)
genelist_down=subset(genelist,logFC< -0.5&Pval<0.05)
head(genelist_down)
```

when I run the codes, it gives results as follows:

```
   logFC         Pval         Gene
1  -0,155887003  0,872819236          Cidec
8  -0,033531014  0,933301176          Stap1
20 -0,034793814  0,965019851        Snora61
24 -0,291441914   0,63454618             Ar
27 -0,118891524  0,810291984          Ddit4
28 -0,090525284    0,8405535  1810011O10Rik
```

Obviously it did not work...
Can someone help me to figure out the problem...

Answer (score 4):

Because of your file formatting where `,` denotes a decimal mark, your columns are all being read as character and hence the subset is giving incorrect results.  Add `dec = ","` to your `read.table()` call and try the `subset()` again.

```
genelist <- read.table(
    "data.txt", 
    header = TRUE,
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE, 
    dec = ","
)

subset(genelist, logFC < -0.5 & Pval < 0.05)
#       logFC        Pval    Gene
# 5 -2.842983 3.95203e-02  Elovl3
# 6 -2.223251 6.17590e-06 Sult5a1
```